# Use std::function to wrap a function with optional arguments (using maybe boost::optional), and serve as a template in another class

Tags: c++, std-function, boost-optional

In my recent project I want to define a `class X` which has an input functional in its constructor, i.e., `std::function<double(const A&, const B&)>`. In real applications, the argument of `class B` is optional (sometimes it will not have this argument). So I am trying to use the `boost::optional` for the second argument in my function. All of `class A` and `B` will show up as template in my `class X`. What is the best way to achieve this behavior I want?

I have tried:

**The code for class X:**

```
template <typename Function, typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
class X{
X(Function _f, A _a, boost::optional<B> _b){
 f_{_f};
 a_{_a};
if (_b){b_{_b};}
}
...
private: 
Function f_;
A a_;
boost::optional<B> b_;

public:
void call_function(Args... args){
  f_(args..., a_, boost::option<B> b_);
}
};
```

**The code for the definition of function `Function f` and instantiation of `X`:**

```
double f_example(const A_actual& a, boost::optional<B_actual> b, const OTHER& other){
...
if (b)...
}
... (declare and define instances of A_actual and B_actual and OTHER)...


X<std::function<double(const A_actual&, boost::option<B_actual>, const OTHER&)>, A_actual, boost::option<B_actual>> x(...);
```

Is this code correct and can achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: FYI you can use `std:optional`.

Comment: What is the difference between std::optional and boost::optional?

Comment: Your code has syntax error, but the idea seems possible.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I just want to show the idea. I did not check the doability of this code. Can you be more specific? How to make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With typo fixed, it would be

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>


template <typename Function, typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
class X
{
public:
    X(Function f, A a, std::optional<B> b) :
      f_{f},
      a_{a},
      b_{b}
    {
    }

    void call_function(Args... args){
        f_(a_, b_, args...);
    }
    //...
private: 
    Function f_;
    A a_;
    std::optional<B> b_;
};
```

and

```
double f_example(const A_actual& , std::optional<B_actual> , const OTHER& ){
// ...
    return 0.0;
}

void foo(const A_actual& some_a,
         const std::optional<B_actual>& some_b,
         const OTHER& some_other)
{
    X<std::function<double(const A_actual&, std::optional<B_actual>, const OTHER&)>,
      A_actual,
      B_actual,
      const OTHER&> x(f_example, some_a, some_b);
    x.call_function(some_other);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yx1aeoYKa)

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the testing demo page!